# AppBarLayout / CollapsingToolbarLayout overlapped by bottom navigation

Tags: android, overlap, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the following activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="[...]android.ui.MainViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation" />

        <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_navigation_height"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:accentColor="@color/bottomNavActive"
            app:defaultBackgroundColor="@{@color/bottomNavBg}"
            app:inactiveColor="@color/bottomNavInactive"
            app:titleState="@{AHBottomNavigation.TitleState.ALWAYS_SHOW}"
            app:useElevation="@{false}" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/floating_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

And a fragment that is displayed in FrameLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="[...]android.ui.home.jobs.JobsViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="navigationViewModel"
            type="[...]android.ui.NavigationViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/extended_toolbar_height"
            android:theme="@style/AppBarLayoutTheme">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/extended_toolbar_title_margin_bottom"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/content_indent_end"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/content_indent_start"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:title="@string/jobs_title" />

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:itemBinding="@{viewModel.itemBinding}"
            app:items="@{viewModel.items}"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

The whole fragment should be displayed above the AHBottomNavigation as folows:

[Desired state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUFHU.png)

However, sometimes when switching tabs or rotating screen the result is as folows (content is overlapped by the bottom navigation; cannot scroll more):

[Bottom menu overlapping the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2n5F.png)

It seems that the root of the issue is somehow in the CollapsingToolbarLayout, not the AHBottomNavigation (does not work even if AHBottomNavigation is replaced by something else).

Do you have any idea where could be the problem? Thanks for any suggestions.